# Python issue with program involving recursion

Tags: python, recursion

For a course I am making a program that must involve recursion. This is what I have so far:

```
def words(letters, start, word):
    while (start) < (len(letters)):
        word = word + letters[start]
        print(word)
        letters = letters.replace(letters[start], "")
        start = (words(letters, start, word))
        return (start + 1)
```

The goal of the program is to accept a list of letters and output all possible combinations of those letters. I am not sure if the program will work, but before that, I am running into another issue. When I run this with a basic command, e.g.

```
words("abcd", 0, "")
```

(the `0` and the `""` are just for starting off the command as they are necessary in the future). But when I run that, it outputs, a  ab  abc  abcd, but then stops with an error citing the line return(start + 1) saying the `start` is not an integer, but a `None type`. When did start become a `None type`? And how can I keep it as an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to return something if the while loop doesn't get entereed (which is basically an if statement in your example):

```
def words(letters, start=0, word=""):
    if start < len(letters):
        word = word + letters[start]
        print(word)
        letters = letters.replace(letters[start], "")
        start = words(letters, start, word)
        return start + 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Also I set some default values, so you can now do this:

```
words(letters="abcd")
```

Comment: The problem with the if statement is that each level needs to be run through several times to output each option, e.g. the word can start with a, b, c, or d, but if you use an if statement, only "abcd" will be outputted.

Comment: @user2832964 your example is basically an `if` statement. It returns on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

When you `return`, you return an `int`. However, you only do so within your while loop, i.e. when `start < len(letters)`. If that condition is not met, your function returns nothing, i.e. `NoneType`.
This is why eventually, in your while loop, `start` becomes a `NoneType`, which leads to your error.

You could do something like this:

```
def words(letters, soFar=''):
  if not letters:
    print(soFar)
  else:
    for i,char in enumerate(letters):
      words(letters[:i]+letters[i+1:], soFar+char)
```